# verify_authenticity_token has not been defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Ruby version 2.2.4, Rails version 5.0.0.1.

I'm getting stuck at a part of a [tutorial](http://lucatironi.net/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/) where you test login with `curl`. I get an error

> ArgumentError (Before process_action callback: verify_authenticity_token has not been defined).

I used this code in sessions_controller:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

Does somebody know the answer?

Comment: check if ```verify_authenticit_token``` exists in your project and change it to ```verify_authenticity_token```

Comment: Sorry this is not the problem. I forgot the "y" of the word  by creating this question. I correct it, thanks

Comment: by the way, in my full project, nowhere is verify_authenticity_token defined. But how and where can I define this method? Is it not in a gem?

Comment: does somebody else has an idea, why I get this Error: ArgumentError (Before process_action callback: verify_authenticity_token has not been defined) ?

Comment: Be sure to not invoke this skip_before_action until protect_from_forgery has been called. Just move it under that in your application controller.

Answer (score 37):

Check if your `ApplicationController` has a call to `protect_from_forgery` as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Essentially calling `protect_from_forgery` adds `verify_authenticity_token` to the `before_filter` list, which you can skip in the other controllers.

Refer to [`protect_from_forgery` documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L122) for more info.

Answer (score 25):

After upgrading to Rails 5, I hit this error. I discovered that if `skip_before_action` is called multiple times with the same method name, this exception will be raised.

My fix was to add the parameter `raise: false`, to the second time `skip_before_filter` was called.

So it would look like this in the Application Controller:

```
skip_before_action :your_method_name, raise: false
```

Answer (score 5):

After upgrading to Rails 5 and deploying to Heroku I hit this error. I could not reproduce it in development.

In the [API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html) the example is given

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
end
```

For me, adding the `unless: -> { request.format.json? }` like the above fixed my stack bomb. `raise: false` unfortunately did not.

Comment: Hi, did that allow unauthenticated access to other routes tho? or does it affect other things?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by setting:
`config.action_controller.default_protect_from_forgery = true` in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a similar issue and none of these solutions worked for me.

Background:
I was re-naming models and controllers to keep the code DRY, I reviewed the files and found that I missed re-naming one of the controllers i.e. the class name was updated but not the file name.

Solution:
Update the controller name to match the new class name.

Moral of the story:
Cross to 't's and dot you 'i's.